# Advanced Custom Field no guarda los datos en post type

Tags: php, wordpress

tengo un campo personalizado creado con ACF el cual lo uso en un Post Type pero tengo el inconveniente que no guarda el valor al momento de crear el post, he aumentado el tamaño del campo en la base de datos y no funciona, le reduje el tamaño del nombre de campo personalizado y funciona, pero por otros motivos necesito mantener el nombre, probé en mi servidor local y no presenta problemas, alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: sin saber cual es el nombre es difícil de evaluar

Comment: El nombre del campo? estate_property_bedrooms tengo campos con el nombre más extenso y funcionan

Comment: cambiando `property` por `properti` funciona? de que tipo es el campo? puede que haya algo raro con como parsea el nombre

Comment: Si cambio un carácter funciona, es de tipo texto. Adicional debo decir que tengo wpml

Comment: yo vería que diferencias hay en la tabla `wp_postmeta` con los campos `_estate_property_bedrooms` entre local y hosting, en lo personal para traducción de campos personalizados debido a problemas similares me pasé de wpml a polylang y para campos traducibles de acf a types toolset (acf lo dejo para campos no traducibles ligado a plugins que lo usan para otras cosas onda nextgengallery) hay algo raro en como elige que option tomar para grabar o recuperar el valor

Comment: agrego: tanto wpml como acf responden rápido a los tickets en las versiones de pago/pro tal vez sea que hay rastros en la base de datos que los confunde o que la lógica del theme sea incompatible y te puedan ayudar a resolverlo